# Как работает равно после открывающего тега <?=

Tags: php, yii2

Начал учить фреймворк yii2 там встретил запись

`<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>`

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name') ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
```

`<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>`

Меня интересует `<?=` как он работает?

Через [гугл](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%20%3C%3F%3D) пробовал искать, он не принимает такие запросы.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это сокращённая запись echo. Запись

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name') ?>
```

Идентична

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'name') ?>
```

---

До музейной версии PHP 5.4.0 этот сокращённый синтаксис был доступен только при включённой опции `short_open_tag`. Если сейчас вам где-нибудь будут попадаться предупреждения, что запись `<?=` непереносима и советы так не делать - не обращайте внимания. Начиная с 5.4.0 этот вариант записи доступен всегда и разрешён к использованию в официальном стандарте [`PSR-1`](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/).

Comment: Вот оно что, все намного проще чем я думал. Спасибо.